# mouseenter is being applied to all elements

Tags: jquery

I have written a bit of jquery which has a timeout function, so after you have hover over the element for a set time a more button appear you then hover that to see a little more about the article.

This all works fine as a seperate element, but I will have more then one.

Each time I hover over one, the effect is applied to all the elements.

Ive tried using $(this).find('') but this doesnt have any effect.

Can anyone help?

Heres the JS fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/8x429/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Article hover function   
var myTimeout;

$('.articleContainer').mouseenter(function () {

    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {

        $('.moreBtn').animate({
            'top': '0px'
        }, 'normal');
        $('.moreBtn').hover(function () {
            $('.moreDetail').animate({
                'top': '0px'
            }, 'slow');
        });

    }, 500);

})

    .mouseleave(function () {
    $('.moreDetail').animate({
        'top': '-335px'
    }, 'fast',

    function () {

        $('.moreBtn').animate({
            'top': '40px'
        }, 'fast');

    });

    clearTimeout(myTimeout);

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have references to the items you want outside of the function scope closures.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Article hover function   
    var myTimeout;

    $('.articleContainer').mouseenter(function () {
        var article = $(this);
        var moreButton = $(article).find('.moreBtn');
        var moreDetail = $(article).find('.moreDetail');
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {

            moreButton.animate({
                'top': '0px'
            }, 'normal');
            moreButton.hover(function () {
                moreDetail.animate({
                    'top': '0px'
                }, 'slow');
            });

        }, 500);

    });

        .mouseleave(function () {
        var article = $(this);
        var moreButton = $(article).find('.moreBtn');
        var moreDetail = $(article).find('.moreDetail');
        moreDetail.animate({
            'top': '-335px'
        }, 'fast',

        function () {

            moreButton.animate({
                'top': '40px'
            }, 'fast');

        });

        clearTimeout(myTimeout);

    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngnqg/1/)

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason why on mouseleave the detail div doesnt hide?

Comment: @user1611354 I just updated my answer. I forgot to define those items for the `mouseleave` handler as well.

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much :) So my only issue was that I did not set my items in variables outside the timeout function?

Comment: @user1611354 Glad you found it helpful. Don't forget to upvote and/or mark an answer as accepted when it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could have the following in it - (setting the `this` variable outside the function within the timeout)

```
$('.articleContainer').mouseenter(function () {
    var el = this;
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).find('.moreBtn').animate({
            'top': '0px'
        }, 'normal');
```